# Read File From Certain Line

Tags: c, fgets

I have a text file whose first line gives some information needed to setup a `while loop`. The while loop should then ignore the already read line and populate an array with the next lines in the file.

**Code**

```
read_success = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_LEN, datafile);

words_read = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value_read);

int foo = value_read;

read_success = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_LEN, datafile); //get the next line

while (read_success != NULL) {

         words_read = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value_read);

         if (words_read >= 1) {

            cpu -> mem[counter + foo] = value_read;

            counter++;

         }

    // Get next line and continue the loop
    //
    read_success = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_LEN, datafile);

}
```

The problem is that my array contains the first line.

I thought by calling `fgets` before the `for` loop would fix this because it would get the new line, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that we can run right away?

Comment: I am trying to skip the first line not the second line. This doesn't seem to work: I get the same result. Thanks, though

Comment: I still get the same result. I even tried adding 5 fgets, but the position stays the same unless it's called within the while loop??